# What's stopping my windows service from running an MSI installer?

Tags: c#, batch-file, windows-services

I have a windows service I've created which is in place to simply poll a git repository, check for new releases, and automatically install new versions of an application I'm building.

When I attempt to run the downloaded MSI installer from inside my windows service, it just will not open. I've tried using both msiexec and running the installer from a batch file which calls msiexec, but I've had no luck. I would like to be able to call the MSI from inside a batch file so I can stick a taskkill command in there to exit the application if it's currently open. Here's the code I've got in place to do all of that.

```
// Build a new batch file to run for our installer routines here
FileInfo InstallerInfo = new FileInfo(InstallerPath);
string InstallerName = InstallerInfo.Name;
string InstallerDirectory = InstallerInfo.DirectoryName;
string UpdateBatchName = $"InvokeUpdate_{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(InstallerName)}.bat";
string UpdateBatchPath = Path.Combine(InstallerDirectory, UpdateBatchName);
string InstallerFileContent =
    "@echo OFF\n" +                                        // Disable echo for the script
    "taskkill /F /IM FulcrumInjector*\n" +                 // Attempt to kill instances of the FulcrumInjector application
    $"msiexec /passive /i \"{InstallerPath}\"";            // Boot the new MSI installer in a passive mode to update the injector

// Write out our installer file content and ensure it exists once done
File.WriteAllText(UpdateBatchPath, InstallerFileContent);
if (!File.Exists(UpdateBatchPath))
    throw new FileNotFoundException($"Error! Failed to build batch file to invoke update for installer \"{InstallerPath}\"!");

// Build a new process to boot our batch file and invoke an update here
ProcessStartInfo UpdaterStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Verb = "runas",                            // Forces the process to run as the user who invoked it
    FileName = "cmd.exe",                      // File to invoke (CMD for booting the batch file)
    CreateNoWindow = false,                    // Specifies if we should make a window for this process
    UseShellExecute = false,                   // Uses shell execution or not
    RedirectStandardError = true,              // Redirects standard output
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,             // Redirects standard error
    WorkingDirectory = InstallerDirectory,     // Sets the working directory of the process to our installer folder
    Arguments = $"/C \"{UpdateBatchPath}\"",   // Arguments to pass into the CMD window when booted
};

// Build our process and store the standard output and error information
Process UpdaterProcess = Process.Start(UpdaterStartInfo);
UpdaterProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (_, ErrorArgs) =>
{
    // Only log out our data for the output if it's not empty
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorArgs.Data)) return; 
    this._serviceLogger.WriteLog("[BAT ERROR] >> " + ErrorArgs.Data);
};
UpdaterProcess.OutputDataReceived += (_, OutputArgs) =>
{
    // Only log out our data for the output if it's not empty
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OutputArgs.Data)) return;
    this._serviceLogger.WriteLog("[BAT OUTPUT] >> " + OutputArgs.Data);
};

// Begin reading the output and error streams for our process
UpdaterProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
UpdaterProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

// Wait for the process to exit out and return based on status
UpdaterProcess.WaitForExit();
return UpdaterProcess.ExitCode == 0;
```

When I go find the batch file I'm writing out, the contents of it are correct, and when I run it manually just by double clicking on it, the batch file executes correctly and opens the installer I'm trying to run. But when I use Process.Start in my code, it doesn't boot the MSI file. I have the output of the batch file redirected, and I can see that it is executing, but the installer never shows up. I see a new instance of msiexec fire open in task manager when the script is run, but nothing ever comes of it. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Did not look in detail: But I guess the install will need to run in a user context?

Comment: Taskkill and msiexec are NOT cmd.exe commands. They are command line utilities taskkill.exe and msiexec.exe, which can both be run directly with arguments! There is therefore no need or requirement for C#, a high level programming language, to have to call on a low level scripting language, to assist in this task. C# also has a process kill method, which means you do not even need to rely upon the taskkill.exe utility at all.

Comment: @Compo yes I understand that. I'm putting those commands into a .bat file and trying to use my C# code to run the .bat file. For some reason, the commands fail to execute when the batch file is called from my code, but work fine if I just double click the batch file or run it through cmd.

Comment: @Fildor providing ALLUSERS to the MSIEXEC command line does not make a difference when the .bat file is called. It behaves the same way no matter what I've tried there. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: A batch file is not required at all, you simply need to understand that and rethink your C# code.

Comment: You need to start the server with an account.  The default account is a system account with no environmental variables.  How are you starting the service?  The service needs to be started with "Run As" using an account that has an environment.

Comment: Maybe try starting msiexec with the "/L" parameter to explicitly let it create a log and hope you get some meaningful content in there.  Whatever the installer does when it does something within the users folders (and many do that) running the service under a service account like "local service" will presumably fail.

Comment: Also have you checked that your msi even supports silent/passive installs? And even if you maybe need to deliver additional arguments via the commandline if they are required.

Comment: Is it this [msi installer](https://github.com/MEAT-Inc/Fulcrum/blob/main/FulcrumInstaller/FulcrumShim.wxs)? If yes it tries to create menu shortcuts and that might be the problem.

Comment: @Compo how would you go about running an MSI installer from within this code then? The code has to somehow kick off the installer. Even if I just directly called msiexec from Process.Start in my C# code, it still doesn't work

Comment: @Ralf yes it is that MSI. I'll see if I can get it to log anything useful out. That's not a bad idea. I'll also try it without desktop shortcuts and see if anything changes.

Comment: @jdweng that may be the issue actually. I am starting it as a system service. I'll see if I can start it as a different user. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

### My Solution

After another few hours of digging through the docs and messing around with `MSIEXEC`, I found a solution. The fix was quite simple. I just had to rewrite my call to `MSIEXEC` using the `/A` flag instead of `/I`. Once I did that, I was able to get the service to call `MSIEXEC` directly from the C# code and execute the installer. I also tossed the use of a batch file and added some C# code in the method I'm building to kill existing instances of the application before my installer runs.

Here's what I ended up with. This solution does not require the addition of a user account using Wix or invoking the call to `MSIEXEC` using a different user account! My windows service is still running under the `Local Service` account and I haven't had issues so far. Hope this comes in handy to someone in the future.

**Note:** The only thing I will mention is that for some reason, my MSI was trying to default to installing the application on my `X` drive instead of on my `C` drive. My solution to that was forcing the `TARGETDIR` property on the installer to `C:\` when I call `MSIEXEC`.

```
// Configure an installer log file here
FileInfo InstallerInfo = new FileInfo(InstallerPath);
string InstallerDirectory = InstallerInfo.DirectoryName;
string InstallerName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(InstallerInfo.Name);
string InstallerLogFile = Path.Combine(InstallerDirectory, $"InstallerLog_{InstallerName}.log");

// Build our argument string for the msiexec process 
string UpdaterArguments =
    $"/A \"{InstallerPath}\" " +       // Install the package as an administrator
    $"TARGETDIR=\"C:\\\" " +           // Specify our target install directory
    $"/L*V \"{InstallerLogFile}\"";    // Sets logging output to the log file name given

// Build a new process to invoke our installer msi file here
ProcessStartInfo UpdaterStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    // Configuration for process bootup
    Verb = "runas",                          // Forces the process to run using the runas verb
    UseShellExecute = true,                  // Uses shell execution or not
    FileName = "msiexec.exe",                // File to invoke. MSIEXEC for installing MSI files
    Arguments = UpdaterArguments,            // Arguments to pass into the MSIEXEC when booted
};

// Build our process and and store the start info built above
Process UpdaterProcess = new Process();
UpdaterProcess.StartInfo = UpdaterStartInfo;

// Start the process and wait for it to exit
UpdaterProcess.Start();
UpdaterProcess.WaitForExit();

// Return out if we've got an exit code of 0 or not 
return UpdaterProcess.ExitCode == 0;
```